# Does this goroutine leak/block forever?

Tags: go

Was curious about the following behavior

```golang
func test() error {
        ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
        cancel()
        doneChan := make(chan bool)
        go func() {
            // emulate a long running function
            time.Sleep(time.Minute)
            // never exits?
            doneChan <- true
        }()
        select {
        case <- ctx.Done():
            return ctx.Err()
        case <- doneChan:
            return nil
        }
}
```

Given the function above, if the `select` statement chooses the context cancellation is the goroutine trying to push onto the `doneChan` blocked forever? Is the solution to simply always have a buffered channel in such cases?

Comment: "Is the solution to simply always have a buffered channel in such cases?" IIRC this is how `time.After` does it

Comment: Ok that makes sense to me just wanted to sanity check

Comment: To not block you can also put the send in a select statement with a default case. That only works if you know that receiver is ready at that time (or not interested anymore).

Comment: yes, it blocks - "sending to a channel when no one receiving"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close this question out...the simple answer is yes.